# Edit compute_amount

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I had edit the funtion of compute_amount everything is okay the problem now is when I pay the invoice I'm still getting the old amount before any change has anyone work on this???
This is my new compute_amount

```
@api.one
@api.depends('invoice_line.price_subtotal', 'tax_line.amount','timbre','partner_id')
def _compute_amount(self):
    if self.type == 'out_invoice':
        if self.partner_id.rs == True:
            print'rs',self.partner_id.rs
            self.amount_untaxed = sum(line.price_subtotal for line in self.invoice_line)
            self.amount_tax = sum(line.amount for line in self.tax_line)
            self.amount_rs = (self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax) * 0.01
            self.amount_total =  self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax + self.amount_rs + self.timbre
        else :
            self.amount_untaxed = sum(line.price_subtotal for line in self.invoice_line)
            self.amount_tax = sum(line.amount for line in self.tax_line)
            self.amount_total =  self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax + self.timbre

    else :
        self.amount_untaxed = sum(line.price_subtotal for line in self.invoice_line)
        self.amount_tax = sum(line.amount for line in self.tax_line)
        self.amount_total = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax
```

Comment: how was the old one?

Comment: this function is for computing the new amount

Comment: Can you put the old one too to compare?

Comment: @api.one
    @api.depends('invoice_line.price_subtotal', 'tax_line.amount')
    def _compute_amount(self):
        self.amount_untaxed = sum(line.price_subtotal for line in self.invoice_line)
        self.amount_tax = sum(line.amount for line in self.tax_line)
        self.amount_total = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax

Comment: Did you re-install the module after the change? did you try to put a log in the function? try to put a log and create an invoice

Answer (score 0):

If it is an on_change method and the field has a readonly attribute, the write method won't get the new value.
For this problem the solution may if you create an invisible mirror function field.

Comment: It is not an on_change method from the first the amount_total is like this    'amount_total' : fields.float(string='Total TTC', digits=dp.get_precision('Account'),
        store=True, readonly=True, compute=_compute_amount),                                                                 I juste edit the compute_amount and how to use a mirror function

Comment: As far as I know, the readonly field is not updateable.
By mirror function I mean an other function field what is a copy from the original field. So you can change a readonly field value and the write method get the new value too. 
`<field name="anOther" on_change="onChange" />
<field name="original" invisible="1" />
<field name="mirror" readonly="1" />`
So in this case when you change the mirror and the original field value, user will sense the new value and the write will get the original new value.

Comment: And if I do it as you have said when the I pay the invoice I will get the new amount??

Comment: and what's the type of the field mirror

Comment: 'field_name': fields.function(_getFunctionValue, type='integer', 'Mirror') the _getFunctionValue is the method what will fill the value, in your case it may dummy method.

Comment: no still getting the old amount when I pay the invoice